# Subclass tool bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitoolbar

I added a toolbar on top of the keyboard, it appears every-time the user clicks on a TextView, it also has a number of buttons that change and interact with the TextView, like for example, changing the text font.

What I'm trying to do now is to create a subclass of the Toolbar so that it can be used on other TextViews, but my problem is:

How to use the TextView delegate methods from inside the Toolbar subclass?

Here is my current code(not all code, for not making the post too big):

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomUIToolbar : UIToolbar{
    UIButton *btn1;
    UIButton *btn2;
    UIButton *btn3;
}
```

**.m**

```
@implementation CustomUIToolbar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        UIBarButtonItem *one = ...
        UIBarButtonItem *two = ...
        UIBarButtonItem *three = ...

        self.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
        self.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:one,placeholder,two,three,four,five,nil];
        [self sizeToFit];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)actionBtn3:(UIButton *) barBtnItem{
    ...
}

-(void)actionBtn2:(UIButton *) barBtnItem{
    ...
}

-(void)actionBtn1:(UIButton *) barBtnItem{
    ...
}

// And the UITextView Delegate Methods

- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
  ...
  return YES;
}

- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CustomUIToolbar class should conform to UITextViewDelegate protocol:

```
@interface CustomUIToolbar : UIToolbar <UITextViewDelegate> {
```

Then you need to assign your CustomUIToolbar subclass as a delegate to textView:

```
self.textView.delegate = self.customTabbar;
```

**Update:**

I think the problem because your toolbar instance is released before the delegate method is called on it. Try to make a property to make sure that variable stays in memory. So instead of:

```
UIToolbar *tool = [[CustomUIToolbar alloc] init];
```

Create a property:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) CustomUIToolbar *tool;
```

And initialize it:

```
self.tool = [[CustomUIToolbar alloc] init];
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you initialize your custom tabbar instance, and assigning the delegate?

Comment: UIToolbar *tool = [[CustomUIToolbar alloc] init];
    self.textView.inputAccessoryView = tool;
    self.textView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

Comment: The problem is when I do this (self.textView.delegate = self.customTabbar;) it shows a warning: signing to 'id<UITextViewDelegate> _Nullable' from incompatible type 'id<UIToolbarDelegate> _Nullable'

Comment: Have you added "<UITextViewDelegate>" to your toolbar interface? (the first line of code in my answer)

Comment: yes: @interface CustomUIToolbar : UIToolbar <UITextViewDelegate>, still the UITexView delegate methods inside my CustomUIToolbar are not called

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I know I'm missing something but dunno what

Comment: Change "self.textView.delegate = self.tool.delegate;" to "self.textView.delegate = self.tool;" and it will work.

Comment: Its the small things...damnit, thanks for the help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make another class for UIextView and import toolbar class in it and call bar button click method from this class. and use textview of this class where it need.

Comment: can you give me an example?